# Database query as variable in Python using MySQLdb library

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to save all data in dictionary (or any thing else which will work) and INSERT to mysql database all variables added to my variable. The problem is that, I don't know how many variables I will have.

It will look like that:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO db_name(keys) VALUES (dict[key])")
```

I have a lot of things in my program, some of them are boolean variables (True, False) and some are integers, others are strings. As default, I can add them like that:

```
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO db_name(a, b, c, d) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %s, %s) """, ('abc', 123, True, 'NULL')
```

As you can see, for string and integer '%s' and for boolean, NULL it must be %s without ''

Reason for this is that, if variable not found, it must be NULL in database, but I don't know how to add string and integer variables as NULL because it uses '%s' which inserts them as string.

Something like that: (its not python code, its just syntaxis idea)

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO db_name( data.keys() ) VALUES ( data.values() ) ")
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I need to generate mysql query using variables. But there are strings, integers and Booleans.

Comment: and any thing can be null? is choosing format string is your problem?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan if i will generate query using variables that i have, all other columns in database will be NULL automatically. But If I cannot generate query I need to add empty variables as NULL

Comment: your problem is if string is null then because of `'%s'` if you supply `'NULL'` then query will insert `'NULL'` instead of `NULL`. Am I correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes, but it would be great to generate query using variables that I have. So, some of variables will not be in the query and in database they will be added as NULL

Comment: I posted an answer below hope it will help up to some extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help, problem solved using format function:

```
query = "INSERT INTO shData("
query_v = "VALUES ("
for key in q_i:
    query += key + ','
    if isinstance(q_i[key],str):
        query_v += "'{" + key + "}',"
    else:
        query_v += "{" + key + "},"
query = query.rstrip(",")
query_v = query_v.rstrip(",")
query = query + ") " + query_v + ") "
cur.execute(query.format(**q_i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using `%s` placeholder in quotes, and also passing a string `NULL` , and not a null value (`None` in python)

Corrected version would be :

```
    cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO db_name(a, b, c, d)
    VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s) """, ('abc', 123, True, None)   
 # no quotes on %s , and None instead of 'NULL'
```

See documentation [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

Comment: Already tested %s but it give error for strings like "abc abc". I know about None, but for %s without '' 'NULL' worked too.